# ¿Por qué no me sale la variable del valor de moneda en AJAX?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, curl

AJAX, javascript, bootstrap json y curl
tengo el siguiente php en el directorio **"js/valida.php"**

```
<?php
$valor_Crypto       = $_POST['valor_Crypto'];
$Money              = $_POST['Money'];

if($valor_Crypto =='BTCTOUSD'){$cryptomoney = 'BITCOIN';    $moneda = 'BTC';
    $url="https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/".$cryptomoney."/";
    $data= file_get_contents('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/'.$cryptomoney.'/',true);
    $json=json_decode($data);
    $price_usd = $json[0]->price_usd;
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING ,"utf-8");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $data = curl_exec($curl);
    $json = json_decode($data);
    $price_usd = $json[0]->price_usd;
    $resultado1 = ($price_usd *5) / 100;
    $resultado2 = $price_usd + $resultado1;
    $resultado = $resultado2*$Money;
    echo "<tr><td><input type='text' placeholder='Result' class='field' readonly='readonly' value='".$resultado ."(USD)= ".$Money."(".$moneda.")'></td></tr>";
}


?>
```

el siguiente js en directorio **"js/app.js"**

```
function busqueda(){
    var variable1 = document.getElementById("cryptomoney").Value;
    var variable2 = document.getElementById("Money").Value;
    var parametros = {
        "variable1" : variable1,
        "variable2" : variable2
    };
    $.ajax({
        data: parametros,
        url:"js/valida.php",
        type: "POST",
        success: function(responce){
            $("#numberbtc").html(responce);
        }
    });
}
```

y por último un **"/index.html"**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body onload="busqueda();">
    <center>Datos:<select class="field" name="valor_Crypto" id="valor_Crypto"  required/>
        <option value="">SELECT CONVERT</option>
        <option value="BTCTOUSD">BTC to USD</option>
<br/>
    <center>Datos:<input class="form-control" type="number" name="Money" id="Money" value="" onkeyup="busqueda();"/>
            <div id="numberbtc"></div>
    </center>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno la respuesta a la pregunta, sería, por que hay un leve desorden entre los nombre de las variables.

En tu pagina HTML tienes los siguentes elementos

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="valor_Crypto" id="valor_Crypto" value="BITCOIN"/>
<input class="form-control" type="number" name="Money" id="Money" value="" onkeyup="busqueda();"/>
```

Donde el ID de estos campos son `valor_Crypto` y `Money`.
Pero en el script el cual envia los datos por AJAX recuperas el los siguientes valores.

```
var variable1 = document.getElementById("cryptomoney").Value;
var variable2 = document.getElementById("Money").Value;
```

Cuando deberia ser así

```
var variable1 = document.getElementById("valor_Crypto").value;
var variable2 = document.getElementById("Money").value;
```

Además al enviar al backend lo que envias son nombres de variables muy distintos a los que esperas recibir

```
var parametros = {
 "variable1" : variable1,
 "variable2" : variable2
};
```

Entonces si, esperas recibir los nombres de los ID en PHP tendria que ser así

```
var parametros = {
 "valor_Crypto" : variable1,
 "Money" : variable2
};
```

Entonces retomando lo anterior, si envias los valores con los nombres que tienen en el `name` o en el `id` de los inputs esta seccion de PHP funcionará sin problemas

```
$valor_Crypto       = $_POST['valor_Crypto'];
$Money              = $_POST['Money'];
```

Pero la condicion de que llegue el valor del submit, nunca se llevará a cabo ya que no estas enviando nada en el valor submit, así que no deberia entrar al primer IF

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

Espero te pueda servir, las observaciones, que obviamente sería una respuesta a tu problema.

Comment: Considera que la propiedad value en JS es con minúscula

Comment: bro en tendi gran parte de su explicacion pero no entendi si no se envian las dos variables eliminare el campo if(isset($_POST['submit'])) pero igual necesitare enviar esas dos variables por que de hecho va es con un select mejor edito la pregunta un poco para que se entienda mejor

Comment: ¿Como haria eso? Aunque si los inputs estuvieran dentro de un form bastaria con hacer jQuery('#elform').serialize() y eso lo envias en la parte del data del request de AJAX #jolsalazar no se como se etiqueta

Comment: Si, bueno mi recomendacion, en realidad no es valida, ya que para usar jQuery("#elform").serialize() deberias usar jQuery, pero por lo que vi no es el caso. Solo emitelo, lo quitaré de la respuesta.

Comment: En realidad nunca estas enviando el campo submit, entonces como no lo envias, si preguntas por el en PHP obviamente no pasará, por que no lo estas enviando. Tienes dos opciones o agregas el input y lo agregamos a los parametros que envias por AJAX o quitas el if donde consultas por submit.

Comment: Aun qe lo hice como me informastes en un principio NO ME DEVOLVIO NINGUN VALOR